# how can I use setInterval when I want to use while in my function?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
<body onload="count()">
    <p id="li1"></p>
    <script>
        let li1 = document.getElementById("li1");
        let x = 0;
        function count() {
            while(x<=1000){
            li1.innerHTML = x++;
            }
        }
        setInterval(count,10)
    </script>
</body>
```

I tried to write for instead of using while but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will reformat your original post shortly. Please be careful to format your future questions properly!

You're doing a few things unnecessarily in your supplied code.

Firstly, you don't need to call `count()` in the `body` `onload`. The `setInterval` will run after DOM load and effectively handle this for you.

Secondly, because you're using `setInterval` to run `count()` every 10ms, you don't need any form of loop, whether it be `for` or `while`. The `setInterval` handles your looping (sort of).

Take a look at the following:

```js
// Get the element we want to put the counter inside
let li1 = document.getElementById("li1"); 

// Init a variable to hold our counter
let x = 0;  

// Init a varible to hold our setInterval timer, so we can disable it when conditions are met.
let counterInterval;

//Define our count() function
function count() {  
    if (x < 1000){
        // Set the innerHTML (I'd rather innerText) to x + 1 as long as x is less than 1000
        li1.innerHTML = x++; 
    } else {
        // If x is equal to or greater than 1000, clear the timer
        clearInterval(counterInterval);
    }
}

//Start our interval time to run count() every 10ms and assign it to our counterInterval variable
counterInterval = setInterval(count,10)
```

```html
<p id="li1"></p>
```